# Increasing Speed of Rotating UIAnimation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uianimation

```
- (void)rotateImageView
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:[self returnTime] delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
        [self.imageView setTransform:CGAffineTransformRotate(self.imageView.transform, M_PI_2)];
    }completion:^(BOOL finished){
        if (finished) {
           if (_player.playing)
                [self rotateImageView];
        }
    }];
}
```

[self returnTime] can return an integer between 1-60, and my animation executes for that long. My problem is that it executes relatively slowly, especially when the runtime is higher. How can I fix this so that the animation is faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `duration:` parameter is the inverse of the speed. That is what duration means: to go a fixed distance in a longer time, you have to go slower. So if you don't want to go that slowly, don't use such high `duration:` values.

By the way, the `duration:` value does not have to be greater than 1. Try `0.3` or `0.5`, for example.

Comment: I'm a little worried that this is not what you really need to know. I think you're trying to accomplish something where you may be going about it the wrong way, and this is why you're really having this problem. I suspect that what you really want to do is rotate at a fast constant speed round and round in a circle _until a certain total time has elapsed_. If so, I suggest you ask another question about that.

Comment: you're right, that's what I'm trying to do =D, but I think this method works. I'm running an image until a AVAudioPlayer stops playing. So in the completion handler in the block above, I simply say if (playing) call self else stop Is any of that bad practice?

Comment: It sounds okay but I don't see the stop condition in the code you provided. Also I'm a little worried about the recursion: you can't do that forever, you know. If this is a repeated animation it would be better to use a ridiculously high repeat count (essentially just telling the animation to repeat forever) and cancel the animation (when the time comes) by removing it from the layer.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21761184/catransaction-rotate-layer-360-degree-strange - look at the second way he does it, using an infinitely repeated 360 degree animation with CABasicAnimation. That is really the best way.

Comment: OK, thanks for the advice. Really appreciate it. I've also edited the code in my question to reflect my previous comment.