# Make a button rotate counterclockwise using CGAffineTransform swift 3 syntax?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation, cgaffinetransform

I'm trying to make a button rotate counterclockwise but for some strange reason it's rotating clockwise. I know the previous way to do it is by `M_PI` but it's been deprecated for swift 3 and replaced with `CGFloat.pi`. I've tried:

```
   self.loginButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -CGFloat.pi)
```

but it still moves clockwise. Any idea what the syntax is to move counterclockwise?

Comment: See the discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21761184/catransaction-rotate-layer-360-degree-strange You need to use core animation.

Comment: You may have forgot to accept the answer given here. It worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 16):

The animation will always take the shortest way. Therefore `CGFloat.pi` and `-CGFloat.pi` animates in same position.

As we need anti-clockwise rotation we forcefully made it a shortest way by using  this  `-(CGFloat.pi * 0.999)`.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations:{

self.loginButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle:-(CGFloat.pi * 0.999))

})
```

There is a better solution than this use `CABasicAnimation` for anticlockwise rotation.

```
let anticlockAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
anticlockAnimation.fromValue = CGFloat.pi
anticlockAnimation.toValue = 0
anticlockAnimation.isAdditive = true
anticlockAnimation.duration = 1.0
self.loginButton.layer.add(anticlockAnimation, forKey: "rotate")
self.loginButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -CGFloat.pi)
```

Comment: This works but I'm not sure the reason why this would work?

Comment: Nice! Thanks for sharing.